# Ubuntu software-center Problems

Tags: software-center

I am running ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell 17r using the windows installer.  I am having software center problems, mainly this one:

and

For the second one it says im running amd64 but im running an intel i5 2nd gen

Comment: Jake, can you be more specific what the problem you're having with the software center is. I think if Ubuntu reports an amd64 operating system, you are are using the main 64bit version.

Comment: Please be more specific on what the problem is, your question is making no sense.

Comment: amd64 is the instruction set which all 64 bit PC architecture CPU's will use. There is no problem.  Please be more specific about your software center problems; your question appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't actually a problem.

AMD64 is the Jargon term for a 64-bit Operating system (Universally), in the same way that i386 is the term for a 32-bit operating system.
Other terms for 64-bit Operating systems include x64, which most people refer it to as.